# Why does IIS seem to be limiting simultaneous connections?

Tags: iis, asp.net, limits

One of the ASP.NET web apps that we have allows users to download relatively large files that can take a bit of time to fetch. For reasons I don't understand, it looks to me like any given client is being throttled to just one connection at a time—that is, downloading a large file stops them from accessing anything else. Hitting the

Is there some built-in limit to either ASP.NET or IIS that I'm missing that can throttle users by default? The developers have assured me they haven't added any custom limiting, and there's no load balancer or anything similarly odd between IIS and the internet.

Comment: You don't know how handy it would be to have a setting in your web server that can throttle your users.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not in the Performance Tab of the Website Properties under Bandwidth Throttling and Website Connections in IIS?